# IndexOutOfRangeException - Windows Phone (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am getting know with Windows Phone, and C# as well. I found out that there is an
IndexOutOfRangeException in my Coloring() function:

```
public void Coloring()
    {
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 171, 169));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 140, 191, 38));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 160, 80, 0));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 230, 113, 184));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 150, 9));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 161, 226));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 229, 20, 0));
        szinek_base.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 51, 153, 51));
        int remove;
        Color szin = new Color();
        Random generator = new Random();
        List<int> lapok = new List<int>();
        for (int l = 0; l < 16; l++)
        {
            lapok.Add(l);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
                szin = szinek_base[generator.Next(0, szinek_base.Count)]; 

                remove = lapok[generator.Next(0, lapok.Count)]; 
                szinek[remove] = szin;
                lapok.Remove(remove);
                szinek_base.Remove(szin);

                remove = lapok[generator.Next(0, lapok.Count)];
                szinek[remove] = szin;
                lapok.Remove(remove);
                szinek_base.Remove(szin);
        }
    }
```

Using try-catch i also found out that the second for() cycle contains the bug.
However if i split into half the block and using try-catch, it wont find error nor in the first part
neither the second. This code works fine under windows 7 as part of a memory game by the way, i am out of ideas. 
Thanks for the help, and sorry for grammatic and other mistakes, i am not aware of StackOverflow protocol, yet.

Edit: Forgot to mention, the main namespace contains them:

```
public List<Color> szinek_base = new List<Color>();
Color[] szinek = new Color[8];
```

Comment: You should inspect the exception stacktrace. This will tell you *exactly* where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From comments and later edit:**

*szinek* it seems to be an array of 8 elements, but *lapok* is a list of 16 elements.

When ***lapok.Count*** is passed to the second parameter of the Random constructor, it means it will might generate something greater than 8 and that will do raise the *IndexOutOfRangeException*

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

My apologies, the initial answer was incorrect. As Adrian has highlighted, the exception is being thrown because the incorrect lists count property is being used to highlight the removable item.

Comment: I don't understand a thing. When count is 8, the generator will generate something between 0 and 7, why it is needed to generate something between 0 and 6, which this is what Count - 1 will do?

Comment: @ThePower Thank you the effort, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard my previous answer. I have located the actual problem...

You set remove based on a random variable which can be anywhere between 0 and 16.

You then try to remove element "remove" from szinek, which may be only size 8.